# pip3 install error when I use virtulenv as general user

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I found the following problem when I tried to install the package using the `pip3` command in a virtual environment.

```
source /bin/activate    ##activate virtualenv

pip3 install aiohttp    ##
```

> error: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno
>   13] Permission denied:
>   '/home/yxs/venv/py34/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/multidict' Consider
>   using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

```
pip3 install --user aiohttp
```

> error: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not
>   visible in this virtualenv.

So, I tried `sudo pip3 install aiohttp`，When I checked with `pip3 list`, I found that aiohttp was installed in the system. Beacause

```
(py34) [yxs@yxs ~]$pip3 list    ## no package named aiohttp

[yxs@yxs ~]$pip3 list    ## found aiohttp
```

How can I install packages into virtualenv?

Edit:

The operating system is CentOS7.5, the default Python version is 2.7, I installed **python3.4** through **epel-realse**, pip3 installed by **get-pip.py**.

I guess the problem is that I have to use command `sudo` to install, but this command will leave the virtualenv environment. Just like the following, but I don't know how to solve this problem. By the way, these operations are excuted in the tmux session.

> (py34) [yxs@yxs ~]$su - root
>
> Password:
>
> Last login: Wed Sep 19 12:07:23 CST 2018 on pts/2
>
> [root@yxs ~]#

All in all, **I can only use root to install the package into virtualenv by command `pip install`**

Comment: Have you installed package with sudo apt-get install python3-pip? Assuming you're using Ubuntu.

Comment: The operating system is CentOS7.5, and I have installed pip3 by get-pip.py.

Answer (score 0):

`Source /bin/activate` means you're using `/bin` root directory of unix/linux.
As you're using python 3. Why don't you use python's builtin `venv` module.
Add `.env` directory into your `.gitignore` file.

Usage

```
python3 -m venv .env
source .env/bin/activate
pip install django
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```